# Get password in Python Programming Language

Tags: python

Is there any builtin function that can be used for getting a password in python.
I need answer like this

Input:
    Enter a username: abcdefg
    Enter a password : ********
If i enter a password abcdefgt. It shows like ********.

Comment: The `getpass` module prompts for a password with echo off, but doesn't show `*****`.

Comment: Is there any option to print * side by side

Comment: @Dinesh are you on windows or a unix-like platform?

Comment: I am using unix platform

Answer (score 4):

#### Original

There is a function in the standard library module [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#module-getpass):

```
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getpass("Enter a password: ")
Enter a password: 
'hello'
```

This function does not echo any characters as you type.

#### Addendum

If you absolutely **must** have `*` echoed while the password is typed, and you are on Windows, then you can do so by butchering the existing `getpass.win_getpass` to add it.  Here is an example (untested):

```
def starred_win_getpass(prompt='Password: ', stream=None):
    import sys, getpass

    if sys.stdin is not sys.__stdin__:
        return getpass.fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)

    # print the prompt
    import msvcrt
    for c in prompt:
        msvcrt.putwch(c)

    # read the input
    pw = ""
    while 1:
        c = msvcrt.getwch()
        if c == '\r' or c == '\n':
            break
        if c == '\003':
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        if c == '\b':
            pw = pw[:-1]

            # PATCH: echo the backspace
            msvcrt.putwch(c)         
        else:
            pw = pw + c

            # PATCH: echo a '*'
            msvcrt.putwch('*')         

    msvcrt.putwch('\r')
    msvcrt.putwch('\n')
    return pw
```

Similarly, on unix, a solution would be to butcher the existing `getpass.unix_getpass` in a similar fashion (replacing the `readline` in `_raw_input` with an appropriate `read(1)` loop).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getpass()` function and then print the number of stars equivalent to the number of characters in the password. This is a sample:

```
import getpass
pswd = getpass.getpass('Password:')
print '*' * len(pswd)
```

The drawback is it does not print `*****` side by side.